# Couple of L'Hospital simplifications and concept clarification.

Tags: calculus

I have 2 questions and a question about my text. In my text I just read this about indeterminate powers:

[image]

and then this:

[image]

So why is it that this example 10 is an indeterminate power? $x^x$ is in the form $0^0$ right? Why do they have to say this:

> Notice that this limit is indeterminate since $0^x = 0$ for any $x > 0$ but $x^0 = 1$ for any $x \ne 0$

Can't they just say that the limit is $0^0$ and that's why it's indeterminate?

**Questions**

1. $$\lim_{x \to \infty} x^3 \cdot e^{-x^2}$$

$$ = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^3}{e^{x^2}}$$

Is this right? From here I can just keep applying L'Hospital's rule until . I get 0 right?

2.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x^{\frac{1}{x}}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\ln{x} ^{\frac{1}{x}}}$$
$$= \lim_{x \to \infty} e^{\ln{1}}$$
$$ = 1$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Again: please don't ask multiple questions in one post.

Comment: What's the reason @AndrewLi? it seems like it gets more done this way and the questions are related

Answer (score 1):

$0^0$ is indeterminate because we have two conflicting properties:

- Anything to the $0$th power is $1$
- $0$ to any power is $0$

Thus, we restrict the first property to apply for bases other than $0$, and the second property to powers greater than $0$. That means, there really is no way of evaluating this: $0^0$—it's an indeterminate form.

In the context of limits, you have to realize, by blindly plugging in you get $0^0$, but different functions may grow at different rates and may give you unexpected results. A good example is:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+{1\over n}\right)^n = e$$

When you blindly plug in $\infty$ you get $1^\infty$ which may seem like it should be $1$, but the power $n$ *approaches* infinity *as $1 \over n$ approaches $0$*, which gives a value of $e$.

---

As for your other concerns: yes you can consecutively apply L'Hopital to find that the polynomial grows slower than the exponential, giving a limit of $0$.

Your second answer is correct, though I'm not exactly sure how you got $\ln1$. I would use log properties to bring the $1\over x$ out and find the limit $\lim_{x\to \infty} {\ln x\over x}$ through L'Hopital.

Comment: Oh I see so the text: "Notice that this limit is indeterminate since $0^x = 0$ for any x > 0 but $x^0 = 1$ for any $x \ne 0$" is really an explanation for why $0^0$ is indeterminate. right? Indeterminate = you cannot determine the limit right?

Comment: @Jwan622 Indeterminate means it can't be determine. So yes, it means the limit can't be determined because you can't evaluate $0^0$.

Comment: How about why my text needs to bring up the points about $x^0 and 0^x$? Why can't we just use the 3 rules listed in the first part of the text?

Comment: @Jwan622 Can you give an example,